# How can I Insert and update in one query

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

Trying to write insert and update in the query. So my scenario is - If a row exists then do upsert and insert a new row. But row didn't exist only do insert.

So here what I am trying -

```
Select exist(Select 1 from table where condition)

if(exists){

Update table set column =value where condition.
Insert into table (column) values (" ").

}else{

Insert into table (column) values (" ")

}
```

As I am writing here so many queries, is there any possibility I can cover all these in one query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "*then do upsert and insert a new row*" makes no sense to me. If the row exists why would you want to insert it _again_? Did you mean to write "then do update and do **not** insert a new row"?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No  didn't mean that. My requirement is like that only. I need to update the previous row (Like planEnd column ) and inssert new row (planStart column)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the definition of the table (as `create table` statement), some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: @jarvis569 . . . Sample data and desired results would really help.  It sounds like you are trying to maintain a type-2 table (one with effective and end dates).

Answer (score 0):

You can write just insert query and check for `CONFLICT` CLAUSE.

Postgresql supports conflict clause, which is triggered when there was some conflict regarding particular `CONSTRAINT`.

Lets say you have table `t` with primary key column `id` and `name` field:

```
CREATE TABLE t ( id integer primary key, name varchar(255));
```

You can check primary key constraint, when you insert:

```
INSERT INTO t (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Name1')
ON CONFLICT ON t_id_constraint
DO UPDATE SET name='Name1';
```

`t_id_constraint` is constraint name for id column uniqueness.
This query will insert new values to table when there is no conflict and will update when new id is found on table.

[Original answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174391/how-to-update-records-else-insert-records-in-postgresql)